# Looking for a book that teaches high-dimensional advanced calculus but not real analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

At the moment I'm reading about partial differential equations from Evans' book. I have a bachelor's degree in Physics (I have a basic understanding in pure mathematics of topology, differential geometry and the like) and wanted to keep learning about the subject. I've noticed that I'm rusty in high-dimensional calculations in a modern way. I tend to do it in a coordinate way where I first try to write down the integral and then "unpack" as a basic calculus integral, but it gets cumbersome and confusing sometimes.

For example I was trying to understand this calculation (everything is in n dimensions):

$$\psi(r) = \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y)dS(y)=\int_{\partial B(0,1)} u(x+rz)dS(z) $$

I understand that using the sphere symmetries the change of origin and normalization can be done and is reflected on the integration variable.  When I try to "unpack" it, I get confused about boundaries and coordinates.

I used the change of variable formula$\int_{\phi(U)} f(v)dv= \int_{U}f(\phi(u))|det |\phi'(u)|du$. Then I realized I've never truly understood how to use the substitution formula for high dimensions.  It was never properly taught to me; all was sort of hand-waved in my physics courses.  In my calculus course they talk about 3 dimensions but no real calculations for n dimensions were done, much less calculations without "unpacking" the integral.

Following the rabbit hole I found out this [Change of variables between different dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4077158/change-of-variables-between-different-dimensions). ...which is new to me. Reading partial differential equations made me realized that I was never really taught [Leibiniz Integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule); it was sort of shown to me by the internet, not my university.

These types of calculations, maneuvers and details are not really explained in our calculus courses, but if I go to a pure math textbook like Rudin they focus on the structure and say nothing about calculations.

I'm looking for a text that explains high dimensional calculations of this sort, but doesn't  get bogged down on the structure of real analysis. I hope a book like that focuses on these procedures and also gives me some "tricks". I'm not looking for a differential calculus book, which is generally understood when asking people to recommend an advanced calculus book. I'm looking to understand calculus in higher dimensions with a calculation-based approach.

I hope this kind of book exists, I would be grateful if you can show me a couple of references in this direction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: +1. But the name is Evans, not Evan.

Comment: By the way, the equation written in the question isn’t correct. If $u$ is identically equal to $1$ and $n=3$, then on the left we’re computing the surface area of a sphere of radius $r$, and on the right we’re computing the surface area of a sphere of radius $1$.

Comment: I think that Griffiths’s book Introduction to Electrodynamics has a very clear intuitive explanation of vector calculus and surface integrals. I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you a quick list. I apologize in advance to all the authors who are not on the list and I am grateful to everyone who will supplement it.

1. Theodore Shifrin - Multivariable Mathematics_ Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds-John Wiley & Sons, Inc. (2005)
2. Tom M. Apostol - Calculus, Volume II_ Multi-Variable Calculus and Linear Algebra, with Applications to Differential Equations and Probability. Vol. 2, ed. 2-John Wiley & Sons (1969)
3. Richard Courant - Differential and Integral Calculus (Volume II)-Interscience (1936)
4. Terence Tao - Analysis II-Springer (2016)
5. John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall (1961)
6. Vladimir A. Zorich (auth.) - Mathematical Analysis II-Springer (2016)
7. Robert Creighton Buck, Ellen F. Buck - Advanced Calculus-Mcgraw-Hill College (1978)
8. Angus E. Taylor, W. Robert Mann - Advanced Calculus-Wiley, 1991

Comment: Hubbard and Hubbard. Advanced Calculus by Harold Edward’s (uses differential forms).

Comment: Thank you for your references!